# inotifywait doesn't work as expected

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I wanted to write a script that triggers some code when a file gets changed (meaning the content changes or the file gets overwritten by file with the same name) in a specific directory (or in a subdirectory). When running my code and changing a file it seems to run it twice everytime since I get the echo output twice. Is there something I am missing?

```
while true; do
   change=$(inotifywait -e close_write /home/bla)
   change=${change#/home/bla/ * }
   echo "$change"
done
```

Also it doesn't do anything when I change something in a subdirectory of the specified directory.

The outpoot looks like this after i change a file in the specified directory:

```
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
filename
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
filename
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce that the script outputs a message twice. Are you sure you don't run it twice (in the background)? Or are you using an editor to change the file? Some editors place a backup file beside the edited file while the file is open. This would explain that you see two messages.

For recursive directory watching you need to pass the option `-r` to `inotifywait`. However, you should not run that on a super larger filesystem tree since the number of inotify watches is limited. You can obtain the current limit on your system through

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

Comment: I don't think that I am running it twice. I added the ouput to my first post - it looks like it would be executed twice, but I just changed content of a file in the directory and saved the file.

Comment: I also just added the moved_to option. When I overwrite it just runs once, which is as desired. The problem ist just when I change the content of afile.

Comment: The editor will create a backup file in the same directory. Try `echo 1 > /home/bla/test.txt`. You should see only one message.